# statistical hypotheses

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance

A company that packages peanuts states that at a maximum 6% of the peanut shells contain no nuts. At random, 300 peanuts were selected and 21 of them were empty.With a significance level of 1%, can the statement made by the company be accepted?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. Are those allowed?

Comment: @AndyBlankertz See this [information](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) about the `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a binomial distribution of size $n=300$ and with parameter $p$ being the probability of an empty peanuts package.

One approach is to get the $99\%$ confidence interval for the parameter $p$ and see if the value $0.06\; (6\%)$ lies within it; if so, the statement of the company will be supported by the sample at the $99\%$ confidence level.

In order to compute the confidence interval you can use 
[de Moivre–Laplace theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem) by which the binomial distribution converges to a Gaussian distribution. In particular, we have:

$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n=300} X_i}{n} 
\;\hbox{converges in distribution to}\;
N(p, pq/n) \,,
$$
where $X_i$ takes on the value $1$ if the package is empty and $0$ otherwise.

Upon this result, the confidence interval is defined as:

$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n=300} X_i}{n} \pm z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \sqrt{pq/n} \,,
$$
where $z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ is the $100\times(1-0.01/2)$-th percentile in the 
standard Gaussian distribution.